do POST request from Bitbucket Pipeline
I'm trying to send a POST request in the Bitbucket pipeline, but only if the docker build fails.
image: node:20

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 3072

pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
      - step:
          name: Build and Push Docker Image
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            # Set up variables
            - IMAGE_ENV_TAG="dev"
            - REPO_NAME="${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}"
            - BUILD_ID="${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}"
            - WORKSPACE="${BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE}"

            # Log in to DigitalOcean Container Registry
            - echo $DO_API_TOKEN | docker login registry.digitalocean.com -u "doctl" --password-stdin

            # Build the Docker image & SEND POST REQUEST
            - docker build -t registry.digitalocean.com/$IMAGE_NAMESPACE/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_ENV_TAG . || { echo "Build failed. Sending error to API."; curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"env\":\"'"$IMAGE_ENV_TAG"'\",\"repo\":\"'"$REPO_NAME"'\",\"buildId\":\"'"$BUILD_ID"'\",\"workspace\":\"'"$WORKSPACE"'\"}' $ERROR_API_URL; exit 1; }

            # Push
            - docker push registry.digitalocean.com/$IMAGE_NAMESPACE/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_ENV_TAG

          artifacts:
            - build/**
    master:
      - step:
          name: Build and Push Docker Image
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            # Set up variables
            - IMAGE_ENV_TAG="prod"

            # Log in to DigitalOcean Container Registry
            - echo $DO_API_TOKEN | docker login registry.digitalocean.com -u "doctl" --password-stdin

            # Build the Docker image
            - docker build -t registry.digitalocean.com/$IMAGE_NAMESPACE/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_ENV_TAG .
            # Push
            - docker push registry.digitalocean.com/$IMAGE_NAMESPACE/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_ENV_TAG

          artifacts:
            - build/**


As you can see at "# Build the Docker image" step, I'm trying to do a POST request with some parameters to an API. For some reason I cannot make it work. Any idea if possible and how to make it work?
Thanks!

Does it throw an error?

Does the "Build failed. Sending error to API." message get printed? I'd suggest you do this in an after-script block, not with bash short-cirtcuits.
